# Unable to authenticate with Godaddy/Office365 using IMAP and Python

Tags: python, imap

I am trying to authenticate and access my emails on a Godaddy/Office365 account using the imapclient library in Python. Despite providing the correct email address and password, I am unable to log in and keep getting a LoginError (LOGIN failed).

```
Here's the code I'm using:

import imapclient
import pyzmail

email = "myemail@example.com"
password = "mypassword"

# Connect to the server
imap = imapclient.IMAPClient('outlook.office365.com', ssl=True)
imap.login(email, password)

# Select the mailbox (folder) you want to read emails from, usually "INBOX"
imap.select_folder('INBOX')

# Search for all unseen emails
uids = imap.search(['UNSEEN'])

# Initialize email content
email_content = ''

# Iterate through the emails
for uid in uids:
    raw_message = imap.fetch([uid], ['BODY[]', 'FLAGS'])[uid][b'BODY[]']
    message = pyzmail.PyzMessage.factory(raw_message)

    # Extract the email content
    if message.text_part:
        email_content = message.text_part.get_payload().decode(message.text_part.charset)
        print(email_content)

imap.logout()
```

Here are the server settings I'm using for IMAP, as provided by Godaddy:

```
Server name: outlook.office365.com
Port: 993
Encryption method: TLS
```

I have double-checked that the email address and password are correct and can log in to the webmail without any issues.

Is there anything I am missing or doing wrong? How can I successfully authenticate and access my emails using IMAP and Python with a Godaddy/Office365 account?

Comment: You cannot log into O365 with a password. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/deprecation-of-basic-authentication-exchange-online  Your alternative is OAuth, which is a much larger undertaking.

Comment: @Max I knew it had to be something like that.